# Why groovy println function prints extra empty line?

Tags: groovy

I noticed the println function in groovy will print extra empty line:

```
  string myline=extractedLine
  println 'myline:'+myline
```

The expected output is '101110' but the actual output shows 2 lines been printed out first line is an empty line and second line is '101110'. May I know how to remove the empty line?

I tried to use print instead of println, but still the same result.

Comment: sorry, but this crap `'myline":+myline` won't even compile

Comment: Apparently it's a typo??

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the value in `myline` itself has a newline character(line feeder or a carriage return), hence try something like the one below.

```
print "myline: " + myline.replaceAll('\n|\r', '')
```

As @tim_yates mentioned if you just have newlines at the beginning or at the end of the string you can simply call `trim()` as well.

```
print "myline: " + myline.trim()
```

Comment: Or just call `trim()`